# How can i keep an Android Device as Server

Tags: android, api, sockets, http, backend

I had a client and a server type of mobile application. The server app is on a tablet and the client app is on several phone devices. Now I want a client-server communication with this tablet and other devices. The client app will send data to the tablet and retrieves data from the tablet. The server app will show the data inserted newly in its UI. How can I achieve this? It possible in android if then please give me a solution. I have googled a lot and read about socket programming. But I didn't find a proper solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the following links for help-

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html this is for server side http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html and for client side